SwaggerV3 - DownloadFile Endpoint
I try to make an endpoint with SwaggerV3 that's download a File in java
Here the endpoint definition in muy interface:
@Path("/file")
@Tag(name = "File")
@Produces({"application/json"})
public interface FileResource extends ApiResource {

@GET
    @Path("/{userId}/pdf")
    @Operation(
            summary = "Export a PDF",
            description = "Export a PDF file",
            responses = {
                    @ApiResponse(
                            responseCode = "200",
                            description = "Success.",
                            content = @Content(mediaType = "application/pdf", schema = @Schema(type = "string", format = "binary"))
                    )
            })
    Single<byte[]> getPDF(
            final AccountRequest accountRequest,
            @PathParam("userId") @ObjectIdParameter String userId);

}

And in my implementation class, I have something like that:
@Override
    public Single<byte[]> getPDF(final AccountRequest accountRequest, final String userId) {
        return Single.fromCallable(() -> {

            // Chemin vers le fichier PDF basé sur l'ID du dashboard
            Path pdfPath = Paths.get("...");
            return Files.readAllBytes(pdfPath);
            
        });
}

But Swagger don't recognize the response Type
Swagger Response
But if I put in media-type:application/octet-stream, I can Download my PDF but with a weird name and it's a binary File
I see a lot of topics on this subject, I try with @Produces Annotations but nothing works
Binary File
Thanks for your help
